Let H be a P subgroup of a finite group $G$ then $(N[H]:H)$ congruent to $(G:H)$(mod $p$)
Can anyone explain the proof of this theorem?
I'm using the text A first course in Abstract Algebra by John B. Fraleigh.
Actually I didn't understand what a normalizer of H means and this proof is about the normalizer so anyone could you please explain?

Please (i) Use MathJax; and (ii) include the question in the body of the post.

$N_G(H) = {g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H}$.

First, I would recommend reviewing the definition of the normalizer:
$$
N(H) = \{ g\in G \colon gHg^{-1} = H\},
$$
and the Sylow theorems. In particular that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups $n_p$ satisfies
$$
n_p \equiv 1\pmod{p}
$$
and that $n_p$ is the index of the normalizer, that is $(G\colon N(H))=n_p$.
Let $|G|=p^a\cdot m$ where $\gcd(p, m)=1$, then $(G\colon H)=m$.
Notice that $(G\colon H) = (G\colon N(H))\cdot(N(H)\colon H)$, giving
$$
m \equiv (G\colon H) \equiv (G\colon N(H))\cdot (N(H)\colon H)\pmod{p}
$$
hence
$$
m\equiv (G\colon H) \equiv (N(H), H)\pmod{p}
$$
as desired.

This result is usually used to prove that $n_p\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, so I would recommend against invoking that fact to prove it. Instead, one should use the  Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem and a  result about the fixed set of a $p$-group action.  (I would also suggest that you wait until the OP cleans up their post before rewarding them with an answer).

Your suggestion is reasonable. In the cited book, this fact is given at the top of page 324, before any Sylow theorems. However, since the fact is proved explicitly in the text, unless OP clears things up, there's no way to help them.

I'm new to this so I don't know how to use mathJax and all so kindly please understand
